# Changing NaN and undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my upload page after an upload is finished instead of displaying the numbers expected it displays undefined and NaN, I was wondering if there was any way I could change undefined to show the file size and NaN to display 0.

Here is an screenshot to show what I am talking about.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrgKd.png

Thank you.
Joe

Comment: please include your code here

Comment: What upload library are you using?  These details are critical to being able to help.

Comment: Its a large script so unfortunately will not be able to copy on here but if you can view source on chillingsafe.com/upload.php and look for the script which starts on line 46 it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How r u fetching the size in your js code? So that we can give clue as close as u expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but everything is fine now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have this function:

```
function updateProgessText(progress, uploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
nowTime = (new Date()).getTime();
loadTime = (nowTime - startTime);
if (loadTime == 0) {
loadTime = 1;
}
loadTimeInSec = loadTime / 1000;
bytesPerSec = uploadedBytes / loadTimeInSec;
textContent = '';
textContent += '' + progress + '% complete';
textContent += ' ';
textContent += '(' + bytesToSize(uploadedBytes, 2) + ' of ' + bytesToSize(totalBytes, 2) + ')';
$("#fileupload-progresstextLeft").html(textContent);
rightTextContent = '';
rightTextContent += '' + humanReadableTime((totalBytes / bytesPerSec) - (uploadedBytes / bytesPerSec)) + ' remaining';
rightTextContent += ' at ' + bytesToSize(bytesPerSec, 2) + 'P/s';
$("#fileupload-progresstextRight").html(rightTextContent);
}
```

You'll want to check if the progress is 100, and if so, show the completed messages. I'm not sure why `uploadedBytes` and `totalBytes` are returning `undefined`, that has to do with the JQuery File Upload Plugin I'm guessing. What you can do is something like this:

```
function updateProgessText(progress, uploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
    if (progress < 100) {
        nowTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        loadTime = (nowTime - startTime);
        if (loadTime == 0) {
        loadTime = 1;
        }
        loadTimeInSec = loadTime / 1000;
        bytesPerSec = uploadedBytes / loadTimeInSec;
        textContent = '';
        textContent += '' + progress + '% complete';
        textContent += ' ';
        textContent += '(' + bytesToSize(uploadedBytes, 2) + ' of ' + bytesToSize(totalBytes, 2) + ')';
        $("#fileupload-progresstextLeft").html(textContent);
        rightTextContent = '';
        rightTextContent += '' + humanReadableTime((totalBytes / bytesPerSec) - (uploadedBytes / bytesPerSec)) + ' remaining';
        rightTextContent += ' at ' + bytesToSize(bytesPerSec, 2) + 'P/s';
        $("#fileupload-progresstextRight").html(rightTextContent);
    }
    else {
        $("#fileupload-progresstextLeft").html('100% complete');
        $("#fileupload-progresstextRight").html('0 seconds remaining');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I could not get this to work.

Comment: Sorry, but without a snippet of your code there's really no way for us to help.

Comment: Viewing source from line 46 is the script chillingsafe.com/upload.php

Comment: Check the edit I made to the answer. I'm not sure why uploadedBytes and totalBytes would be returning undefined. I'm guessing that has to do with the jQuery plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much everything works perfect now and with this code added when the progress reaches 100% the (undefined B of undefined B) just simply goes away, which in my opinion is a lot better than having the info there at all. Again thank you.

Comment: Good to hear! No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this statement:

```
rightTextContent += '' + humanReadableTime((totalBytes / bytesPerSec) - (uploadedBytes / bytesPerSec)) + ' remaining';
```

You have missed to specify `humanReadableTime` for `(uploadedBytes / bytesPerSec)`. So it should be:

```
rightTextContent += '' + humanReadableTime((totalBytes / bytesPerSec) - humanReadableTime(uploadedBytes / bytesPerSec)) + ' remaining';
```